# Is There a Way to Blur Sensitive Fields?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a web developer for a school system and am often asked to give presentations of my websites using the live sites. The problem is some of these sites contain student names, and I've been asked to blur/mask/hide the student names when giving demonstrations.  Is there a simple way to do this?  I'm developing using VS2012 C#/html5/bootstrap/jquery.  All of my sites have the same basic design: use bootstrap functionality as much as possible, and simple html `<table>` structures.

Comment: What did your searches turn up? A quick search for "CSS text blur" reveals no shortage of articles.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder unfortunately my search term choice was horrible, I started Googling using the phrase "html blur sensitive information" and instead of coming back with helpful articles it returned things telling me why blurring data is a bad idea...I guess I was having a bad day, I never could figure out how to simplify my search to get better results :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy to blur the text in CSS, the basic idea behind it is, set the color of the text to transparent and add text shadow to it, so that the visible part will be the shadow, but not the text. This will create a quite good blur effect. For example, consider the css code given below

```
.blur-text
{
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}
```

Here it will produce the blurness in the text as shown in the image below,
                          [image]

Now, you can easily adjust the blurness of the text by easily changing the width of the shadow, so as to make it more clearer or fade.
For more information on how to create a blur effect visit [Creating a Blur Effect](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-blurred-text-effect/)

Comment: This was perfect, thank you...I've created a new column in my database user table called "securityBlur".  I can simply set that column to true for any user, and in my code I check to see if it is true, and if it is, I add my new "blur-text" class for whichever fields need it!!

Comment: That's great ! It worked for you, I also use this technique for my work. By the way, If you liked my answer, please Upvote it also